# Driver return code 1 xdvipdmx generating output pdf may not be valid

Tags: errors

Hi Can anybody shed light on why the below query is now actually working?

I took the following steps:

added %&--no-pdf as the first line of my TeX file.
Recreated the error (on the affected clients service)obtained xdv file and ran xdvipdfmx -E -vv against it, found nothing of use in the output.
Removed the no pdf line and regenerated the document - it now never errors!  how on earth can this be?? None of the hundreds of document templates fail now.  Is it possible some cache exists that has now had something written to it???

Hi could anybody offer advice on this one? I am trying to determine root cause of a fault with xelatex / xdvipdfmx.

The process terminates leaving a 0kb pdf and message:

> Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;
>   file DOCUMENTVIEWER_1490973454755_191_06776504744697253363.pdf may not be valid

The document file name is produced by other software ahead of passing to xelatex. I am suspicious of the length of it.. The 0kb pdf is also not openable with adobe, so it's clearly corrupt.

Using the simplest TeX file I can make, the compilation by xelatex completes fine (as far as I can see in the log). However the next line following is the error above.

The main problem is I cannot replicate the issue either from the command line or in other similar environments through our software.
I have seen some other posts on here regarding using `--no-pdf` argument; the problem, however, is I cannot get that into a replicable scenario without a build and that is not feasible.

So as I say I can't reproduce the problem from the command line. Can anybody offer any advice as to what may be going on here?

I have checked windows event logs on the server and cannot find anything. I feel I have completely ruled out user permissions both application and 'human' in my investigation.

It would be useful if I could insert an instruction into a TeX file to tell it not to output a PDF and give me a xdvi instead

Comment: You are writing a lot about that you can't reproduce the error or can't find anything but more or less no facts about your environment and the document and the exact nature of the error. On can guess windows (which version?), but it is unclear how you call xelatex, which is the "other software", what is the content of the tex file, log-files, where they are located ... .

Comment: Hi Thanks, I suppose i was really looking for advice on the kind of things in your experience that can lead to this problem with the final pdf creation. To give more ideas on things I can work with. windows server 2008 R2 standard

Comment: All sorts of problems can lead to a failure of compilation. fonts, postscript, code, .... "It didn't work" is not enough as a clue.

Comment: The compilation of the document text does not fail: it is at the pdf creation stage - We have a dev server with the same latex installation and the problem does not occur on there.

Comment: Our software is a java enterprise application - we build a string to call xelatex as follows with the arguments as shown: {A}/xelatex.exe --interaction=batchmode –quiet --include-directory={B}/images --aux-directory={C} {D}

Where {A} is the path to the xelatex folder
{B} is the path to a folder containing image resources
{C} is a temp folder
{D} is the full path and name of the tex file.

Comment: my test file is as simple as: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{edp}

\usepackage{edp}

\begin{document}
\arial

TESTING123

\end{document}

Comment: the log file ends as follows,(E:\app\clientname\data\clients\xyz\temp\DOCUMENTVIEWER_1490973454755_191_06776
504744697253363.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3448 strings out of 429156
 43719 string characters out of 3170464
 115044 words of memory out of 3000000
 6675 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 12870 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 786 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,5n,42p,555b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Comment: Then the very next error is the original couple of lines I quoted

Comment: sorry for the terrible formatting of my replies,

Comment: Is there any way to add a tag or argument into the tex file itself to not produce a pdf?

Comment: You don't need to add all this info in the comments. You can edit your question. Beside: Your class is a local class, so it can't be tested. And as you didn't show the exact file pathes it is difficult to test the issue. But imho it is a rather bad idea to call xelatex with a full path to a file and to use --include-directory and --aux-directory in such scripts.

Comment: I have found I can use this:  %&--no-pdf